# Why WSAEACCESS when re-opening UDP socket?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, winapi, winsock

My program needs to be able to close and later re-open a UDP socket to receive data.  The socket will always be using the same port and `INADDR_ANY`.

When I try to re-open the socket, I am always getting `WSAEACCES` from the `bind()` call, despite enabling `SO_REUSEADDR`.

Here's a summary of the code to open the socket:

```
SOCKET      sock;
SOCKADDR_IN sin;
BOOL        bTrue;
DWORD       dwTrue;
sock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0 );
if( INVALID_SOCKET == sock ){/*report*/}
bTrue = TRUE;
if( SOCKET_ERROR == setsockopt( sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&bTrue, sizeof(bTrue) ) ){/*report*/}
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
sin.sin_port        = htons(18889)
sin.sin_family      = AF_INET;
if( SOCKET_ERROR == bind( sock, (SOCKADDR*)&sin, sizeof(sin) ) ){/*report*/}
dwTrue = TRUE;
ioctlsocket( sock, FIONBIO, &dwTrue );
```

Currently, the socket is both created and destroyed by a thread, which is also destroyed after the socket is closed. IOW, the thread calls `closesocket()` just before it terminates. The re-open attempt is being made in a new instance of the thread.

According to netstat (run as admin), there is nothing holding the UDP port open after it is closed, and the `WSAEACCES` error is not helping me to figure out why I cannot open the port a second time.

Since I can open the port the *first* time, I clearly have permission, so I'm at a loss about what could be wrong.  Any ideas would be welcome.

**EDIT**: Well, that's interesting... The open function succeeds when all of the open/close socket stuff is done from the main thread.  Not sure why there should be any prohibition on two different threads reusing an address/port when `SO_REUSEADDR` has been set to TRUE.

So, I'd still like to figure out/understand *why* it doesn't work when one thread opens/closes the socket and all subsequent threads try (and fail) to reopen the socket.

**EDIT**: I spoke too soon.  Once I make a `recvfrom()` call in the thread,                                               the next time I try to reopen the socket, it fails with `WSAEACCES` again.  (FWIW, I don't have any `send()` or `sendto()` calls).  So, I'm still stuck, and I may be forced to incorporate the thread into the main program.

**EDIT**: Sigh.  After eliminating the UDP thread completely, I still get the `WSAEACCES` error when I try to bind a new socket to the previously used address/port AFTER having performed a `recv()`.  If the data source is not transmitting, I can keep closing sockets and creating new ones bound to the port indefinitely.  But a single `recv()` (`FD_READ` event) stops that from working.

So I am **still** stuck trying to understand *why* something that seems like it *SHOULD* work is not working.

Comment: Are you able to open / close / reopen in a simple single threaded program?

Comment: A UDP socket doesn't need to be opened, let alone "re-opened", since it has no connection that gets automatically closed.  Once you do close it, the socket is gone, never to be seen again, and you must create a new one by calling `socket()` (or `WSASocket()`)

Comment: I suspect that you mean creating a new socket and binding it to the same local interface and UDP port that was previously bound to a now-closed socket.  That reuses the port but does not reuse / reopen any socket.

Comment: The code sample I posted is from my `opensocket` function.  Sorry, I think of a socket as _open_ when I can use it for communication -- I didn't realize that would be a point of confusion.

Comment: According to Microsoft's documentation, `bind()` reports `WSAEACCES` only when you try to bind a UDP socket to a broadcast IP without enabling `SO_BROADCAST` first. That being said, can't you just create+open the socket once and reuse it across multiple threads? Do you really need to destroy and recreate a new socket for every thread?

Comment: This is a test program designed to display incoming data from serial or UDP.  The user can turn either source on or off and change the port/parameters at will.  So I need to close the socket when the user tells me to and then re-open it, possibly with the same port, but that one aspect doesn't want to work.  WSAEACCESS also says "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions." but since the code doesn't change, what "permission" has changed by a recv() call that prevents me from assigning the port to a new socket after the existing one is closed?

Comment: Oh, I should also point out that as of EDIT3, I no longer HAVE a thread performing UDP operation.  All of the UDP is now handled by the main window procedure in the main thread.  I still have the same problem once `recv` has been called.

Comment: According to the Doc:[Using SO_REUSEADDR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/using-so-reuseaddr-and-so-exclusiveaddruse#using-so_reuseaddr)The SO_REUSEADDR socket option allows a socket to forcibly bind to a port in use by another socket. The second socket calls setsockopt with the optname parameter set to SO_REUSEADDR and the optval parameter set to a boolean value of TRUE before calling bind on the same port as the original socket. Once the second socket has successfully bound, the behavior for all sockets bound to that port is indeterminate.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT I've read the docs many times and discovered that SO_REUSEADDR is also necessary to use the same port that was used on a recently closed socket.  What I cannot understand is why I get WSAEACCESS when I have CLOSED a UDP socket (that I used in a recvfrom() call) and try to bind a new socket to the same port.  The docs seem to say this is EXACTLY what SO_REUSEADDR should allow.  The error description is useless, since I'm not using a broadcast addr.

Comment: For more details about WSAEACCES, you could refer to the Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/error-10013-wsaeacces-is-returned

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT That doc might be helpful if I were using TCP or Windows Server and executing that `netsh` command that I've never heard of before.  BUT... As _clearly_ stated, I'm using UDP.  Also, though I did not say this, I'm using Windows 10 Pro.  Regardless, I've worked around the bug in Windows by never closing the socket until a _different_ port is selected for use (I just discard incoming data when the port is "closed".)